# What is the word for the opposite of "preferred"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

*Non-preferred* sounds clunky to me and words like *alternative*, I feel, don't convey the sense of "the set of things I really don't like".

**Edit:** Perhaps the context will help. In this version, I've used tchrist's suggestion of *disliked*:

> Most parts of the brain have preferred patterns of input that those parts link to     characteristic patterns of output. Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of input it dislikes or cannot link the preferred input to its characteristic output.

I want to avoid too much anthropomorphism because this is for a scientific paper. The field already uses the word "preferred". In the section intended for a general audience I wanted to avoid using technical words but not accidentally convey something.

Comment: I think in this field, [*unpreferred* is what you probably should stick with.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=neurobiology+preferred+pattern+vs.+unpreferred+pattern+&oq=neurobiology+preferred+pattern+vs.+unpreferred+pattern+&gs_l=hp.12...9331.12145.4.13724.3.3.0.0.0.0.120.346.0j3.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.gNFzJ1HQ9aY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3266efb6d9a31251&biw=1262&bih=550)

Answer (score 4):

Both *unfavored* and *disfavored* exist, and may serve. But perhaps the somewhat stronger *disliked* or *disapproved* is what you mean here.  If that’s the route you plan to take, there are plenty of even stronger terms for things you don’t care for: *hated, deplored, loathed, abhored*.

Answer (score 3):

> Most parts of the brain have preferred patterns of input that those parts link to characteristic patterns of output. **Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of input it dislikes** or cannot link the preferred input to its characteristic output.

Perhaps the bolded line can be reworded to one of:

- *Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **atypical** input ...*
- *Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **unsuitable** input ...*
- *Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **incompatible** input ...*
- *Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **inconsistent** input ...*
- *Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **unacceptable** input ...*

Comment: I absolutely love "unsuitable"! I think "atypical" might be too nebulous, in this context, because the preferred patterns for one area can be "atypical" in the sense of very specific.

Comment: @mac389 I see. In that case, _ill-suited_ might be another potential candidate ...

Answer (score 2):

In terms of describing neurological function to a lay audience, I would suggest that *abnormal* expresses your concept simply.

> Most parts of the brain have preferred patterns of input that those parts link to characteristic patterns of output. Many disorders arise when a brain region receives patterns of **abnormal** input or cannot link the preferred input to its characteristic output.

You might also prefer *aberrant*, which expresses something that is different and perhaps unexpected.

You noted that I wrote "patterns of abnormal input" rather than "abnormal input patterns." It depends on whether you want to say that the pattern is abnormal or the input is abnormal.  I hadn't thought about it much, but if you mean that the firing pattern is pathological, then I would write "abnormal patterns of input."  If you mean that the afferent process is abnormal, then "patterns of abnormal input" would make more sense.  However, when writing for a lay audience, I don't think most readers would understand the distinction without further elaboration.

Comment: I'm curious on your opinion on the difference between "patterns of abnormal input" and "abnormal patterns of input". Instinctively I write the latter, but you wrote the former. Am I splitting hairs?

Comment: @mac389: The first modifies *input*, while the second modifies *patterns*. In your context they more or less mean the same thing. I prefer Kit's version in your case.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more alternatives to pick over. I believe that many disorders arise when a brain region..:

- ..receives patterns of **unfamiliar** input..
- ..receives patterns of **unexpected** input..
- ..receives **confusing** patterns of input..

(or my favourite)

- ..receives **anomalous** input..

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity is often the best approach. I would suggest you use '**non-preferred**'.

> Most parts of the brain have preferred patterns of input that those
>   parts link to characteristic patterns of output. Many disorders arise
>   when a brain region receives **non-preferred** patterns of input or cannot
>   link *a* preferred input to its characteristic output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try *distaste or detest*.

> distaste: mild dislike or aversion
>
> detest: dislike intensely.

definition source: NOAD