# Another word for the opposite of "prefer" in the sense of "decreasing the preference for (but not dismissing it)"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for another word to use as the *opposite* of prefer. The searches I looked up show this has been [asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85220/what-is-the-word-for-the-opposite-of-preferred) [before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171993/non-negative-opposite-of-to-prefer), but not quite in the context I was looking for.

Here is the context, and I apologize for going technical:

```
                    +------+
                    |      |
       +------------+  R2  +---------------------+
       |            |      |                     |
       |            +------+                     |
       |                                         |
+------+            +------+                  +--v---+
|      |            |      |                  |      |
|  R1  +------------+  R3  +------------------>  R5  |
|      |            |      |                  |      |
+------+            +------+                  +---^--+
       |                                          |
       |            +------+                      |
       |            |      |                      |
       +------------+  R4  +----------------------+
                    |      |
                    +------+
```

> R1 has three paths to get to R5.  One through R2, one through R3, and another through R4.  All three paths are viable, but some paths might be more preferred than the others.
>
> There are configurations changes we can make to have *R1 **prefer** paths through R2*.  And there are configuration changes we can make to have *R1 **de-prefer** paths through R4*.

Specifically, I am looking for a substitute for `de-prefer` in the text above. Similar to de-prioritize, or [dis-prefer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95733/is-dispreferred-a-mainstream-word-in-english), but I don't think either of those words do it quite justice or work for simple conversational English.

In either case, the path through R4 is never "negated", it is always a viable path, but only when the paths through R2/R3 are not available.

The very specific context is I am trying to provide instructions to students who will be applying the configuration changes discussed above. The best I could get so far is:

> In case xyz, **de-prefer** the path through R4

But again, I don't think that sounds right.

Comment: @lawrence Yea, I can see the confusion. I need the opposite of "*preference as in increasing the preference for*" (and not picking between two choices, or between one preferred and one disliked). I'm open to suggestions on rephrasing.

Comment: Try something like *revert to 'no preference'*.

Comment: @Lawrence Tried something new. I think that clears it up.

Comment: You can talk about the *precedence ordering* and thus lower/decrease the precedence for the path through R4

Comment: What's wrong with *disfavor*, suggested in both of the questions you linked? Does it need to be more absolute than that, or less? That is, do you want to say you can make R-1 go from preferring R-4 to feeling neutral toward it, or do you want to go from neutral/preferring to viewing R-4 as a less-favored option than the others, or even not an option at all?

Comment: deprecate is another possibility

Comment: @1006a I can't explicitly define it, but *disfavor* doesn't feel right. It doesn't quite communicate "reducing the preference" verses picking one from another. The choices are not binary, I may increase the priority for the path through R2, then "deprioritize" the path through R3, then further "deprioritize" the path through R4... (thanks @jxh) creating a hierarchy of all viable paths, but in an order of preference.

Comment: You know, the word 'avoid' does cover what you want, too.

Comment: @yosefbaskin It is too permanent though. "avoid" implies indefinitely. In my case, the "deprioritized" path should still be used if the other "prioritized" paths fail. Where as "avoid" seems to imply "at all costs". Either way I appreciate thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen and used ***deprioritize*** in contexts similar to yours.

> (*transitive*) To reduce the level of priority of.
>
> > *Do you want me to **deprioritize** my current report to get this done?‎*
>
> <sub>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprioritize)</sub>

So:

> There are configurations changes we can make to have R1 prefer paths through R2. And there are configuration changes we can make to have R1 **deprioritize** paths through R4.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the most natural way  to do it would be to "prefer" the negative.

> "I perfer not to discuss such matters"

In your example

> There is are configurations changes we can make to have R1 prefer paths through R2. And there are configuration changes we can make to have R1 ***prefer paths not through R4***